# Unable to match date with datetime

Tags: python

I wanted to convert a date from git log but I'm trying to match the date from the documentation of datetime but it never matches.

```
from datetime import datetime
receivedDate = (commits[0]['Date']) #receiving date
print(receivedDate)      #e.g Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016 +0100      
receivedDate = ' '.join(receivedDate.split(' ')[:-1])  #removing +0100
date = datetime.strptime(receivedDate,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

> ValueError: time data 'Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016' does not match format
>   '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'

I've also tried by keeping '+0100' and added %z, but it doesn't work either.
It runs with python 3.6.

---

Thanks for help or any idea :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) where you don't need to provide a format string.

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse('Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016'))
#2016-01-14 12:47:30
```

Also I am able to use your datetime format as well.

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
#2016-01-14 12:47:30
```